# How to enable auditing on macOS for docker containers?

Tags: docker, audit

I'm trying to use [bench docker for security](https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security) to check for vulnerabilities and fix them.

I followed the instructions and built an image and run it, but the auditing warnings are showing. They stated that I should enable auditing.

But I'm having problem enabling auditing on macOS and I can't figure how to do it. Is it possible?